# Premake, command line options don't do anything

Tags: lua, compilation, build-system, premake

I have the following section in my lua script:

```
newoption {
    trigger     = "build-tests",
    description = "Build tests."
}

configuration "build-tests"
    print("bbbbbbbbb")
    include("Src/tests/tests.lua")

configuration "not build-tests"
    print("aaaaaaaaaaa")
```

running `premake5 gmake --help` gives:

```
Usage: premake5 [options] action [arguments]

OPTIONS - General

 --build-benchmarks  Build benchmarks.
 --build-tests       Build tests.
 --debugger          Start MobDebug remote debugger. Works with ZeroBrane Studio
 --fatal             Treat warnings from project scripts as errors
 --file=FILE         Read FILE as a Premake script; default is 'premake5.lua'
 --help              Display this information
```

However running `premake5 --build-tests gmake` outputs:

```
bbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaa
Building configurations...
Running action 'gmake'...
Done (362ms).
```

BOTH versions are running, I don't understand. I am trying to get a toggle to select whether I want to build tests or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configuration()` is a function, not an `if-then`. Your example above is equivalent to...

```lua
configuration("build-tests")
print("bbbbbbbbb")
include("Src/tests/tests.lua")

configuration("not build-tests")
print("aaaaaaaaaaa")
```

It has no effect on which code runs or does not run in your script; *all* the code in your script is always run, and then the configuration conditions are evaluated later.

Instead look at the actual generated project output to see if things are working or not.